# How can I get ElasticSearch aggregations to count the parent documents instead of the nested documents

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

My ElasticSearch index has nested documents to indicate the places where various events occurred related to the document. I am using aggregations to get facets of the places. The count returned is the count of the number of occurrences of the place. For example, if a document has a birth and death place of California, the aggregation count for California is 2. I would like the aggregation count to be the number of documents containing a particular place, rather than the number of child documents containing the place. The relevant part of my schema looks like this:

```
"mappings": {
    "document": {
        "properties": {
            "docId" : { "type": "keyword" },
            "place": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "id": { "type": "keyword" },
                    "type": { "type": "keyword" },
                    "loc": { "type" : "geo_point" },
                    "text": { 
                        "type": "text",
                        "analyzer": "english",
                        "copy_to" : "text"
                    }
                },
                "dynamic": false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can get facets with a simple aggregation like this, which retrieves the places with type place.vital.* (e.g. place.vital.birth, place.vital.death, etc), but counts the number of nested documents, not the number of parent documents.

```
"aggs": {
"place.vital": {
  "aggs": {
    "types": {
      "aggs": {
        "values": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "place.id"
          }
        }
      },
      "terms": {
        "field": "place.type",
        "include": "place\\.vital\\..*"
      }
    }
  },
  "nested": {
    "path": "place"
  }
}
```

Is it possible to tweak my aggregation so that it only counts each parent document once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use reverse nested aggregation. This will then create an aggregation with the nested counts and a sub aggregation with the parent counts.

See [how to return the count of unique documents by using elasticsearch aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27553916/how-to-return-the-count-of-unique-documents-by-using-elasticsearch-aggregation/27578607#27578607) for more detail.

Answer (score -1):

I'm sure you can do it with nested fields, but not with parent child relationships. If you are looking for places Why don't you search on places index and filter by child?

[Has child query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-has-child-query.html)

Comment: My first thought was the reverse nested aggregation. And yeah...that obviously only works on nested. I don't think there's an equivalent for parent child. Might not even be possible with the way those documents are indexed.

Comment: Yes, that doesn't exist on parent-child relations. Another aporoach is to denormalize data and serialize all the event data on the place index, but that could not perform well depending on the number of events per place.

Comment: guys, he is using nested field... so why are you talking about parent child relationships?

Comment: You are right. My mistake. That could be done with a reverse nested aggregation.